# Ext.net MVC Razor Cell double click on gridpanel

Tags: c#, ext.net

I want to double click on a cell of a gridpanel an call another
action/view with extra parameter example:
The gridpanel is in .../Student and I want to show the details of one
student in another page ex: /Student/Detail/1 double clicking on his
name, id, or wherever data is on his record.
Sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
@(
  Html.X().GridPanel()
                 .Title("Students")
                 .Width(550)
                 .Height(200)
                 .ForceFit(true)
                 .Store(Html.X().Store().Model(Html.X().Model()
                     .Fields(fields =>
                     {
fields.Add(Html.X().ModelField().Name("StudentID"));
fields.Add(Html.X().ModelField().Name("LastName"));
fields.Add(Html.X().ModelField().Name("FirstMidName"));
fields.Add(Html.X().ModelField().Name("EnrollmentDate"));
                     }
                     )
                 ).DataSource(Model)
     ).ColumnModel(
             Html.X().Column().Text("Student ID").DataIndex("StudentID"),
         Html.X().Column().Text("Last Name").DataIndex("LastName"),
         Html.X().Column().Text("First Name").DataIndex("FirstMidName"),
Html.X().DateColumn().Text("Enrollment").DataIndex("EnrollmentDate")
     ).DirectEvents(de =>
         {
             de.CellDblClick.Url = "Edit"; // also tried
de.CellDblClick.Action = "Edit";
             de.CellDblClick.ExtraParams.Add(1);           //static
later I'll add the StudentID here
         }
        )
)
```

The gridpanel show the data without problem but when I doubleclick on a
cell this is the request that it's sended
localhost:10782/Student/Edit?_dc=1359052548829
instead of this
localhost:10782/Student/Edit/1

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to manage an URL with a Before handler.

To remove "?dc..." from an URL, please set up DisableCaching="false".

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>

    <script>
        var counter = 1;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />
    <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Test">
        <DirectEvents>
            <Click Url="Some URL" Before="o.url = o.rawUrl + counter++;" DisableCaching="false">
                <CustomConfig>
                    <ext:ConfigItem Name="rawUrl" Value="Controller/Action/" Mode="Value" />
                </CustomConfig>
            </Click>
        </DirectEvents>
    </ext:Button>
</body>
</html>
```